# How do I log a user in with the Facebook API and use Django the user?

Tags: python, django, facebook

So I have been developing an application for awhile now and originally I used Django user model so I have a bunch of checks similar to

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
```

and

```
@login_required
```

in my code. Now I have just gotten Facebook login "working" after probably 2 months of fiddling with different methods of testing it, however I have some questions.

Is there a way for me to sign in a Django user when someone signs in with Facebook? That way I can use all the Django user model functionality I already have in my code.

Or am I going to have to do all those checks with the Facebook API? If so, want to give me some hints on how to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can [customize](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/) the [Users authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.login).

Then autenticate when you autenticate FB login
from django.contrib.auth import login

```
def my_fb_logon(request):
    // your user code
    ...
    if loged:
        user.backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
        login(request, user)
```

You'll need to manually specify the authentication backend because you're not calling authenticate() first.